# How do I display the latest Flickr OAuth embedded image on the frontpage?

Tags: flickr

I have a Flickr category among my blogposts where I just paste in the direct links from Flickr, and let OAuth do it's thing to hotlink/embed the photos in the post.

On my frontpage I am trying to grab the latest hotlinked/embedded photo from the latest post in the Flickr category in order to display it there. But with no success. I've tried with the `get_the_image();` plugin, but it seems to only read photos that have been inserted into the post using the wordpress gallery.

I manage to get `the_title();`, so I know I'm accessing to the right category and post, but I don't have any chance of displaying the image. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**Update:**
I've achieved this with the following code:

```
query_posts('category_name=flickr&showposts=1');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$meta = get_post_custom();      
$photos = array();
foreach ($meta as $key => $value)
    if (false !== strpos($key, 'oembed'))
        array_push($photos, $value[0]);                 
    if(preg_match('/src="(.+\.jpg)"/i', $photos[0], $m)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $m[1] . '" />';
    }

endwhile;
endif;
```

Unfortunatly that embeddes the full size image from Flickr. I tried combining it with [TimThumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/), but with no success. Small steps...

Answer (score 1):

Embeds are cached in hidden custom fields of a post. You can retrieve all keys with [`get_post_custom()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) of latest post and loop through it, looking for array key that starts wih `_oembed_`.

Comment: Thank you, this set me off in the right direction. I had to get further help to put some pretty ugly code together. I've updated my question to reflect it.